# Reducing the size of a video exported with AVAssetExportSession - iOS Swift

Tags: swift, avfoundation, ios11, avassetexportsession, avkit

I'm currently exporting a video in the following way:

```
   let exporter = AVAssetExportSession.init(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPreset1280x720)
   exporter?.outputURL = outputPath
   exporter?.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
   exporter?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
   exporter?.videoComposition = mainCompositionInst
```

A 15s video consumes about 20MB in data. Comparing this to Snapchat's 2MB videos, this number seems totally unacceptable.

I already reduced the quality of the export- and capture session (1280x720).

The video is filmed on a custom camera. `UIImagePickerController` is not used.

AVAssetExportSession is used with default settings.

Is there any way I can reduce the size of my videos? 
Thanks a lot!

**EDIT 1:**
I tried to use this library: https://cocoapods.org/pods/NextLevelSessionExporter

Unfortunately, this creates sizing problems and removes my audio:

```
// Creating exporter
    let exporter = NextLevelSessionExporter(withAsset: mixComposition)
    exporter.outputURL = outputPath
    exporter.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
    exporter.videoComposition = mainCompositionInst

    let compressionDict: [String: Any] = [
        AVVideoAverageBitRateKey: NSNumber(integerLiteral: 2500000),
        AVVideoProfileLevelKey: AVVideoProfileLevelH264BaselineAutoLevel as String,
        ]

        exporter.videoOutputConfiguration = [
            AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.h264,
            AVVideoWidthKey: NSNumber(integerLiteral: 1280),
            AVVideoHeightKey: NSNumber(integerLiteral: 720),
            AVVideoScalingModeKey: AVVideoScalingModeResizeAspectFill,
            AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey: compressionDict
        ]

        exporter.audioOutputConfiguration = [
            AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC,
            AVEncoderBitRateKey: NSNumber(integerLiteral: 128000),
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: NSNumber(integerLiteral: 2),
            AVSampleRateKey: NSNumber(value: Float(44100))
        ]
```

[image]

Comment: Not a duplicate, the context is different. I am using AVAssetExportSession here.

Comment: Have U tried another export preset options - e.g. `AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality` ?

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan Yes, but the quality is unacceptable bad.

Comment: @holex "AVAssetExportSession is used with default settings." - Thanks for your toxic comment.

Comment: @dfi, the comment was not toxic at all, my friend, the default settings give you 20MB large video, are you expecting some kinda random miracle or what? change the specs and you can get different size of output. piece of cake... but you may need to define how much _loss_ of the video's quality you are willing to accept to get a smaller output, without that your post makes no sense at all, I'm afraid.

Comment: @holex That's why I'm asking this question .. (???). I do not find any references on that and I do not know how I can efficiently tweak the settings.

Comment: @dfi, as per you still need to define what kinda _loss_ of the video quality you can accept to get a still decent output, after that it is easy to find the _efficient_ settings to create such output... until you can define the _loss_, you cannot find _efficient_ setting either – neither could anyone else for you. I hope you understand the causality here...? _e.g.: is it 1 FPS of your video okay for you? no? what is the minimum FPS you seek? 60? or need 240 for slow-mo? well, you are doomed. could you accept 12 FPS, maybe? there might be something then, etc..._ if you see the flow here.

Comment: @dfi This problem is correlated to this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50700076/avmutablecomposition-resizing-issue

Comment: @thelearner hey man, I am in the same exact situation that you was in. Do you have GitHub link with the code that you used to get this working? I'm using AVExportSession and a 15 sec HighestQuality video is 27mb, MediumQuality is 1 mb but looks horrible. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To reduce file size try these properties for setting up `HEVC` codec (use cocoa pod `NextLevelSessionExporter`):

```
let compressionDict: [String: Any] = [
AVVideoAverageBitRateKey: NSNumber(integerLiteral: 2500000), //lower it if you wish
AVVideoProfileLevelKey: AVVideoProfileLevelH264BaselineAutoLevel as String,
]
exporter.videoOutputConfiguration = [
    AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecType.hevc,
    AVVideoWidthKey : NSNumber(integerLiteral: 1280),
    AVVideoHeightKey: NSNumber(integerLiteral: 720),
    AVVideoScalingModeKey: AVVideoScalingModeResizeAspectFill,
    AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey: compressionDict
]
```

You need to upgrade to `macOS High Sierra` and `iOS 11` in order to use `HEVC` video codec. But if you can't use `HEVC` for some reason, use regular `H.264` with lower bitrate.

```
AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecType.h264:
```

[image]

> Also, look at this [SO post about video bitrate in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46778436/output-video-size-huge-using-hevc-encoder-on-ios).

Comment: first of all, thanks a lot for helping me! Your answer reduced the size from 20MB to stunning 4MB. I love you, dude!. You don't know how long I researched to achieve this. - You are my hero. I wasn't able to use HEVC, so I used h264 as you suggested. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Сheck the type of data contained in samplebuffer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23216610/ios-avassetwriter-writes-video-but-does-not-record-audio

Comment: Hello andy! After days of hustling, I finally managed to fix my problem. There is an active bug in iOS 11, that causes sizing issues with mirrored videos. I mirrored the video manually and it is now working perfectly fine. Bless you for your help!

Comment: I am getting NextLevelSessionExporter, writing failed, Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 \"The operation could not be completed\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12780), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x282fb4570 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12780 \"(null)\"}}" all the time..any one faced this issue

Comment: I don't know why. I tried it in Xcode 9, all worked fine.

Comment: I am picking video file using UIImagePickerController and creating AVURLAsset

Comment: I suppose you should ask dfi about it. Maybe he saw a similar error.

Comment: For HEVC, the profile should be set to `kVTProfileLevel_HEVC_Main_AutoLevel` from the `VideoToolbox` framework, found this comment in `AVVideoSettings.h`: `/* HEVC profiles/levels are defined in VideoToolbox/VTCompressionProperties.h, e.g. kVTProfileLevel_HEVC_Main_AutoLevel. The constants defined there can be used as the value for the key AVVideoProfileLevelKey. */`

Comment: Thank you very much @MosheGottlieb, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 7):

cracked this finally.

Use `exportSession.fileLengthLimit = 1048576 * 10 //10 MB`

10MB is hard coded number. Use according to your required bitrate.

> fileLengthLimit /* Indicates the file length that the output of the
>   session should not exceed.  Depending on the content of the source
>   asset, it is possible for the output to slightly exceed the file
>   length limit.  The length of the output file should be tested if you
>   require that a strict limit be observed before making use of the
>   output.  See also maxDuration and timeRange. */

Answer (score 2):

Lalit Kumar's answer works perfectly. On top of his solution, I wrote an AVAsset extension so that I can easily set the bit rate, as opposed to the file size. The equation in the `preferredBitrate` method is my original. You could have a hard coded table instead.

```
extension AVAsset {
    private var preferredBitRate: Float {
        //          720p   1080p
        //  30fps:   5.0    11.3
        //  60fps:   7.5    16.9
        // 120fps:  11.3    25.3
        // 240fps:  16.9    38.0 (Mbps)
        guard let videoTrack = self.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first else {
            return .zero
        }
        let size = Float(min(videoTrack.naturalSize.width, videoTrack.naturalSize.height))
        let frameRate = videoTrack.nominalFrameRate
        return pow(1.5, log2(frameRate / 30)) * pow(size / 720, 2) * 5
    }

    private var preferredFileLength: Int64 {
        // 1 Mbit := 125000 bytes
        return Int64(self.duration.seconds * Double(self.preferredBitRate)) * 125000
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set the fileLengthLimit value, the video bitrate value of the file generated by the exportSession changes.
That's exactly what I wanted.
If you want to set the video bitrate value of the `AVExportSession`, calculate and set the `fileLengthLimit` value of the `AVExportSession`.

Like this:

```swift
exportSession.fileLengthLimit = Int64(Double(preferredBitrate / 8) * video duration)
```

Thanks Lalit Kumar.